# XBee Transmit Request broadcast

Tags: xbee

I'm trying to send a broadcast using a router on a XBee S2 network.
All the devices are properly configured and have joined the network, but the packet is not being received.

I'm sending

`7E 00 11 10 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00 41 42 43 2A`

to the module.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the **16-bit network address** to 0xFFFE.

You have to send

`7E 00 11 10 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FE 00 00 41 42 43 2D`